# Datatables - Rowspan em <tbody>: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-datatables, table, datatable

Estou usando JQuery e o plugin DataTable em minhas tabelas. Então, em algumas situações eu preciso usar rowspan no corpo (`tbody`) de minhas tabelas, o que gera o seguinte erro no Google Chrome e acaba não aplicando o plugin:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined`

Eu li a respeito do plugin `fakeRowspan`, porém ou ele não funcionou ou eu não consegui usá-lo corretamente.

Veja o fiddle abaixo com o problema:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mayconfsbrito/9mkHz/6/)

Comment: Qual o resultado esperado?

Answer (score 1):

Rapaz, dei uma olhada nesse plugin `jquery.datatable.js` e o mesmo tem aprox 12.000 linhas.

Para não dar o erro adicionei o teste na linha do erro **669**:

```
if(nCell)
    nCell.className += ' '+oCol.sClass;
```

Depois começou a dar um alerta que eu comentei nas linhas, 781 a 784:

```
/*
_fnLog( oSettings, 0, "Requested unknown parameter "+
(typeof oCol.mData=='function' ? '{mData function}' : "'"+oCol.mData+"'")+ 
" from the data source for row "+iRow );
oSettings.iDrawError = oSettings.iDraw;
*/
```

Segue o link do JSFIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/9mkHz/7/

Comment: Olá Rogerio, eu conferi o seu Fiddle, porém parece que o plugin acabou não sendo aplicado corretamente devido as modificações que você teve que inserir.

Comment: @mayconfsbrito, dada a complexidade do plugin acho meio difícil resolver esse problema de forma rápida. Sugiro vc olhar na pagina deles e veja se esse plugin dá suporte para o que você deseja fazer.

Comment: Obrigado Rogerio. Vou olhar no próprio fórum do DataTables.

Answer (score 0):

Sei que esta minha resposta não vai resolver o seu problema (e eu pesquisei bastante sobre ele e a única referência que eu achei o link para ela não existia mais, conforme pode ver neste [link](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/5979/use-rowspan-for-td-element-causes-wrong)) Mas seguem algumas dicas sobre a sua tabela para que isso evite problemas futuros com o seu código:

- Você tem id's repetidas nela, como por exemplo: #tabelainfo e #corpotabela;
- As propriedades colspan e rowspan quando com valores iguais a 1 não são necessárias;
- A tag  foi descontinuada, recomenda-se o uso de CSS para isso;
- A propriedade "align" nas td's também não é recomendada, para isso use CSS;
- Faltam linhas na tabela, nesta mixagem de linhas e colunas algumas foram esquecidas, para saber onde elas estão coloque um border="1" na tabela e veja os espaços vazios, isso com certeza vai evitar problemas futuros no próprio dataTables().

Lembrando que acima são apenas dicas que eu percebi ao buscar uma resolução para o seu problema olhando no versionamento 6 do seu fiddle.

Como estou trabalhando atualmente com o DataTables também e tendo alguns problemas com ele, vou continuar pesquisando e se achar uma solução para esta dúvida eu volto aqui novamente.